# Hibernate HQL query on map with composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, composite-key

I have the following map in my hibernate configuration which is creating a table with a composite primary key:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="my.package.Item" table="item"
        ...
        <map name="itemSources" table="item_source" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="item_id" />
            </key>
            <map-key-many-to-many class="my.package.SourceProperties" column="source_id"/>
            <element type="text" node="externalId">
                <column name="external_id"/>
            </element>
        </map>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am trying to query all "items" for whom the "itemSources" includes a particular source id.

I have tried several HQL queries (shown below) to no avail.

**1st approach**

```
select it.id from Item it where :srcid in elements (it.itemSources)
```

This results in a query for the value of the map i.e. external_id (as opposed to the key of the map):

```
... where ('4' in (select itemsour2_.external_id from item_source itemsour2_ 
where item1_.id=itemsour2_.item_id))
```

**2nd approach:**

```
select it.id from Item it where :srcid in elements (it.itemSources.source_id)
```

This gives an exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: source_id

**3rd approach:**

```
select it.id from Item it join it.itemSources itsources where index(itsources.id) = :srcid
```

This gives exception:
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of my.package.SourceProperties.id

Is there a correct way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use the annotations it's very easy

Comment: @AbdessamadHALLAL this is in a large project with XML config and I cannot switch to using annotations. Has to be an HQL query unfortunately.